# Move the card a container to corresponding container using cdk Angular material

Tags: angular

I have a number of containers. In the case when I drag the item from a container to drop the item in specific other containers of all containers, at the time show only specific containers corresponding to which you drag an item from the container.

Comment: Could you please add a code sample to your question? it would also help if your could be a little more descriptive. you have used the word "Container" 8x in your question...

Comment: container refers to an Array of Objects. Item refers to Object. I want to move the Object only to its corresponding array. I resolved the problem using the mouseDown event